# "They have great senses of humor" or "They have a great sense of humor"

Tags: articles

> 1-They have great senses of humor
> 2-They have a great sense of humor

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ELL!

In the UK we generally avoid "They have great senses of humour." In conversation we will go **all round the houses** to avoid it. We might say, "*She has a great sense of humour. They **both** have*". Or we'll simply say, "*They have a great sense of humour.*"

When you Google "have great senses of humor", the examples found are mostly from social media rather than literary sources. Switch to Google Books and the result is similar. (In the UK, with *'humour'*, the first few books include *'Your Best Friend – Is You'* and *'Catvinkle'*.)

In the UK, although we speak of [our senses of humour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our+senses+of+humour%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif7MLShILuAhWSrHEKHbGeDEYQpwUIJQ&biw=1366&bih=666&dpr=1) and [their senses of humour](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1944%2Ccd_max%3A2008%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=g6TyX5K8Foaj1fAPx8q8yA0&q=%22their%20senses%20of%20humour%22&oq=%22their%20senses%20of%20humour%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...492380.495601.0.496218.8.8.0.0.0.0.76.473.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.TO7loKVnENk) we avoid [great senses of humour](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great%20senses%20of%20humour%2Cgreat%20sense%20of%20humour&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreat%20senses%20of%20humour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20sense%20of%20humour%3B%2Cc0) and [good senses of humour](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good%20senses%20of%20humor%2Cgood%20sense%20of%20humor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgood%20senses%20of%20humor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgood%20sense%20of%20humor%3B%2Cc0).

Although the [US](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great%20senses%20of%20humor%2Cgreat%20sense%20of%20humor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=6&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreat%20senses%20of%20humor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20sense%20of%20humor%3B%2Cc0) and the [UK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great%20senses%20of%20humour%2Cgreat%20sense%20of%20humour&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=6&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreat%20senses%20of%20humour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20sense%20of%20humour%3B%2Cc0) *seem* to be in agreement about this, *"**have** great senses of humor"* is used more frequently in the US than in the UK:

US [(got,have,their)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got%20great%20senses%20of%20humor%2Chave%20great%20senses%20of%20humor%2Ctheir%20great%20senses%20of%20humor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20great%20senses%20of%20humor%3B%2Cc0)
UK [(got,have,their)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got%20great%20senses%20of%20humour%2Chave%20great%20senses%20of%20humour%2Ctheir%20great%20senses%20of%20humour&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=)

Comment: Very informative answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"They" can be used collectively, e.g. "The editors of The Onion have a great sense of humor," becomes "They have a great sense of humor." Or you could talk about two friends with very *different* senses of humor, e.g. on is droll and the other slapstick, so you might write, "They have great, though antithetical, senses of humor."

It's like "fish" or "fishes".

> He caught two salmon and ate both fish.
> Salmon and trout are related fishes.